# AngularJs Array not Binding To Template

Tags: html, angularjs, binding, controller

I have a controller named **dataController**, two services, named **dataHttpServices** and **dataLocalServices** and an html template, some directives.

In my html template, I have two different tabs uses same controller and add item to list in my controller from two different places.

In debug mode, I see the data change properly but the data binding is not working properly.

I don't know What is my mistake, help please. In code;

Here is Html;

```
<div 
    class="metadataSelect"
    layout="column" 
    ng-model="selectedItems" 
    ng-show="selectedItems.length > 0">                                 
    <div layout="row" ng-repeat="item in selectedItems">
        {{item.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller;

```
$scope.addSelectedItem = function (selectedItem) {
    var found = false;
    var self = this;

    dataLocalService.addSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    $scope.selectedItems = dataLocalService.getSelectedItems();
};
```

And here is the service;

```
this.selectedItems = [];

this.addSelectedItem = function (item) {
    this.selectedItems.push(item);
};

this.getSelectedItems = function () {
    return this.selectedItems;
};
```

I call **addSelectedItem** from scope in two different button's click event with **ng-click**.

If I first add an item by click the first button and click the second button (first click the first button), the button binds the array to div correctly.

But when I add an item by click the second button before click the first button, the array does not bind to div.

After add some items to array by click the second button, when I click the first button, bind all the elements to div. For example three element at once but doesn't bind without clicking the first button.

What is my mistakes. Thanks for helps.

Comment: By only showing us snippets of your code it is hard to identify the context ('self' in controller and 'this' in the service).  It's likely that the root of your issue is in the code we can't see.  Please provide all of the relevant code ... a plunker would be really nice.

Comment: Why do you have that `ng-model="selectedItems"` in the div ".metadataSelect" ?

Comment: what GabrielHobold said and also why do you keep `$scope.selectedItems = dataLocalService.getSelectedItems();` inside `$scope.addSelectedItem` ?

Comment: that is right about the ng-model. I put the getSelectedItems() because i want to bind the data when i add a new item to list.

Comment: I made this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fkUCwcBlzTbdsMRgaZpt?p=preview) trying to simulate your situation and everything works well, I think there's some mistake that's not shown in the code above

Comment: @jbrown I couldn't find any website to make plunker with material design. Because i call the method from different tabs. And i see the plunker Gabriel Hobold. This is only add something from one button's click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with using **$scope.$watch**. And I think the problem is their scope is different because i create controller twice with **ng-controller**. Here is the code snippet i found to solve it.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedItems', function () {
    $scope.selectedItems = $metadataLocalService.getSelectedItems();
});
```

This solves my problem. Because watch is tracking the related data changes and etc.